# Find a sum, terms given as ratios of improper integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Given
$$\alpha_k =\frac{\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac {x^{k-1}} {e^x -1 } dx }{ \displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{e^x} dx }; \quad k\in N$$
find
$$\frac {\alpha_2}{1} -\frac{\alpha_6}{15} +\frac {\alpha_{10}}{125} -\frac{\alpha_{14}}{875} +\frac {\alpha_{18}}{5625} -\frac {\alpha_{22}}{34375} +\cdots $$

Comment: Where are the denominator numbers coming from?

Comment: The numerator of $\alpha_k$ is the zeta function, and the denominator is just a factorial, but unless there is some information on the coefficients I doubt any summation attempt can be done.

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in a way suitable for assigning homework.  That is probably the reason for the down-votes and the votes to close the question.

Comment: In case it helps, the denominators $1$, $15$, $125$, $875$, ... appear to be in the form $(2n+1)5^n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\int _0^\infty \frac {x^{k-1}}{e^{ x }-1 } dx &=\Gamma(k)\zeta(k) \tag1\\\\
\int _0^\infty \frac {x^{k-1}}{e^{ x }} dx &=\Gamma(k) \tag2
\end{align}
$$ and that the first terms of the sequence $\displaystyle \left\{(2k+1)\times5^k \right\} $ are given by
$$
1,15,125,875,5625,34375,\ldots
$$ Then the series you are looking for is
$$
S=\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\zeta(4k+2) }{2k+1}\left(\frac15\right)^k. \tag3
$$ From the standard [power series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) of the digamma function,
$$
\psi(1+z)=-\gamma-\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^k\zeta(k+1)z^k,\quad |z|<1,
$$ one may deduce that
$$
\begin{align}
2\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(4k+2) }{2k+1}z^{4k+2}&=\log \left(\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z) \right)-\log \left(\Gamma(1+iz)\Gamma(1-iz) \right) \tag4\\\\
&=\log \left(\frac{\pi z}{\sin (\pi z)}\right)-\log \left(\frac{\pi z}{\sinh (\pi z)}\right)\\\\
&=\log \left(\frac{\sinh (\pi z)}{\sin (\pi z)}\right).
\end{align}
$$ Hence

> $$
> \sum_0^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(4k+2) }{2k+1}z^{4k}=\frac{1}{2z^2}\log \left(\frac{\sinh (\pi z)}{\sin (\pi z)}\right),  \quad |z|<1,\tag5
> $$

from which you may obtain $(3)$.